# DategridView insert into another oracle Table C#

Tags: c#, oracle, datagridview

I have a Datagridview of 46 columns consists of Date, Int and String Type. I want to insert the values to another oracle table.

```
private void loopGrid()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow datarow in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            writeRecord(datarow);
        }
    }

    private void writeRecord(DataGridViewRow datarow)
    {

        string sqlqry = "insert into Table  (Date,Number) values(:Date,:Number)";

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlqry, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":Date", datarow["DATE"]))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":Number", datarow["Number"]));
        cmd.CommandText = sqlqry;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

I don't quite understand what I did wrong about passing the parameters. I'm pretty new to C#, what's the right way to pass the Datatype and value to the other oracle table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the Oracle driver you are using, there may be an overload for the `.Add` method that accepts the value as the second parameter, or there may be an `.AddWithValue` method that does it explicitly.  I *think* for ODP.net you have it right as just `.Add`.

Either way, these will derive the datatype from the datatype of the value.

Regarding your parameters, you need to omit the colon `:` character when invoking the parameters.  I know in SQL Server, Sybase, SQLite and others you include them (a `@` in those cases), but in Oracle you leave them out during the parameter declaration.  Interestingly, I think PostgreSQL accepts either methodology.

As such, I think this will work:

```
private void writeRecord(DataGridViewRow datarow)
{

    string sqlqry = "insert into Table (Date,Number) values(:Date,:Number)";

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlqry, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Date", datarow["DATE"]))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Number", datarow["Number"]));
    // cmd.CommandText = sqlqry;  -- not necessary, handled in constructor
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

If not, maybe try explicit conversions with either the type or value:

Yuck:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Date", Convert.ToDateTime(datarow["DATE"])))
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Number", Convert.ToDecimal(datarow["Number"])));
```

Better:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DATE", OracleDbType.Date,
    datarow["DATE"], ParameterDirection.Input);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Number", OracleDbType.Decimal,
    datarow["Number"], ParameterDirection.Input));
```

And if worse comes to worse, the bulletproof (although verbose) way to do it would be:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DATE", OracleDbType.Date));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Number", OracleDbType.Decimal));
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = datarow["DATE"];
cmd.Parameters[1].Value = datarow["Number"];
```

As a footnote, this last way is actually preferred if you have multiple rows to insert, as you create the parameters once and modify the values and execute the insert multiple times:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DATE", OracleDbType.Date));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Number", OracleDbType.Decimal));

foreach (DataRow datarow in datarows)
{
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = datarow["DATE"];
    cmd.Parameters[1].Value = datarow["Number"];

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

-- EDIT --

Based on your feedback and my improved proofreading skills, this is what I'd recommend.  I added a transaction in there for good measure:

```
string sqlqry = "insert into Table  (Date,Number) values(:Date,:Number)";

OracleTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlqry, conn, trans);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("DATE", OracleDbType.Date));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Number", OracleDbType.Decimal));

foreach (DataGridViewRow datarow in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = datarow.Cells["DATE"].Value;
    cmd.Parameters[1].Value = datarow.Cells["Number"].Value;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

trans.Commit();
```

For what it's worth, you also need some exception handling.

Comment: Can not apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow.  Red line under datarow["Number"]. It doesn't recognize, what can I do ?

Comment: Oh, I assumed datarow was a DataRow (System.Data.DataRow) based on your problem statement -- I didn't realize it was a grid row.  I think this is how you would normally get the value from a grid row: `datarow.Cells["Number"].Value`.  If that works, let me know, and I can update the answer.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out before I got your answer lol. Another problem I have is infinite loop. I thought it will stop after reading the last row of the datagrid but it kept running infinitely. Do you know why? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I can't see anything in your code snippet that would cause that...  my only thought is that you have an event that is triggering `loopGrid()` that may be firing it based on something happening inside `loopGrid`.  Can you post more code?  Also, apologies -- you had the corrent datatype in your example.  I was not paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to use:

```
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(DbType.Date, datarow["DATE"]))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(DbType.Double, datarow["Number"]));
```

Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.dbtype(v=vs.110).aspx